# IndexError: list index out of range in codewars puzzle

Tags: python, indexing

As a beginner in Python I decided to have a go at the Codewars puzzles.

Codewars uses Python 2.7.6.

The second puzzle requires you to:

Write a function that will return the count of distinct case-insensitive alphabetic characters and numeric digits that occur more than once in the input string. The input string can be assumed to contain only alphabets (both uppercase and lowercase) and numeric digits.

For example, if you give the program "abcde" it should give you 0, because there are no duplicates. But, if you give it "indivisibilities" it should give you 2, because there are 2 duplicate letters: i (occurs 7 times) and s (occurs twice).

As a beginner I came up with an approach that I imagine is very crude, but nevertheless it works perfectly on my system:

```
def duplicate_count(text):
    # the number of duplicates
    dupes = 0

    # convert input string to lower case and split into individual characters
    list_of_chars = list(text.lower())

    # sort list into groups
    sorted_chars = sorted(list_of_chars)

    # get length of list
    n = len(sorted_chars)

    # check whether the first element of the list is the same as the second. If
    # it is, add one to the dupes count
    if sorted_chars[0] == sorted_chars[1]:
        dupes += 1
    else:
        dupes += 0
    # start with the second element (index: 1) and finish with the (n - 1)-th
    # element
    for i in range(1, n - 1):
        # if the ith element of the list is the same as the next one, add one
        # to the dupes count. However, since we only want to count each
        # duplicate once, we must check that the ith element is not the same as
        # the previous one
        if sorted_chars[i] == sorted_chars[i + 1] and sorted_chars[i] != sorted_chars[i - 1]:
            dupes += 1
        else:
            dupes += 0

    return dupes
```

This passes all of the automated tests, but when I submit this as a solution I get an STDERR:

```
Traceback:
   in <module>
   in duplicate_count
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As I understand it, this error is given if I try and access an element of the list that does not exist. But I cannot see where in my code I am doing that. I calculate the length of my list and store it in `n`. So let's say I supply the string `"ababa"` to `duplicate_count`, it should generate a list `sorted_chars`: `['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']` of length 5. So `n` = 5. Therefore `range(1, n - 1)` = `range(1, 4)` which will generate the numbers 1, 2 and 3. Thus `for i in range(1, n - 1)` is, mathematically speaking, for each i ϵ I = {1, 2, 3}. The largest index I therefore use in this code is 4 (`if sorted_chars[i] == sorted_chars[i + 1]`), which is fine, because there is an element at index 4 (in this case 'b').

Why, then, is Codewars giving me this error.

Comment: What if the string has one or zero characters?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem aha! Then I have a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your function requires at least two characters to work.  Try running `duplicate_count('a')` and see the error it throws.  Add the following after `n = len(sorted_chars)`:

```
if n < 2:
    return 0
```

That will stop running the rest of the function and return 0 duplicates (because you can't have any if there's only one character).

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the comment before I hit post.